# Arcmap Layout View Blank Map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts

I am trying to get my map to appear in layout view but when i click on the icon (at the bottom left) the layout view is just blank.  Then when i go back to data view all my layers appear again.

How do I get a layer to translate to layout view?

Comment: Click the Full Extent icon in the Tools toolbar, your data frame is maybe not centered on the data

Comment: If you have multiple frames, make sure you are activating the correct one not the empty frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the data / items you want to see in the layout view. Switch to the layout view and explore the `insert` menu and its `dataframe` option.

You should read this detailed [tutorial](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/a-quick-tour-of-page-layouts.htm) for step by step instructions